# How to add data table items in a combo box?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function which return a list of countries as data table. How do I add these row values to a combo box?

```
For Each row as DataRow in fooDataTable.Rows
    combobox.Items.add(row)
Next
```

Some how this does not fill up the values on my combo box. The datatable returns 100 rows. Each row has 2 columns. I am trying to add all the 100 datarows with the first column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting `combobox.DataSource = fooDataTable` and then set `combobox.DisplayMember = "your field name"`

Comment: set a breakpoint and look at how many items the CBO has after that.  it might be **what** you are adding.  I am not sure what `.ToString` returns for a `System.Data.Datarow`

Comment: It just returns something like System.something.. It's not retriving the values.

Comment: then do what @LarsTech suggested no need to iterate them unless you want the data from both columns to display

Comment: Do what@LarsTech said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataRow` is an object and while objects can be added to a Combo or ListBox, in this case the result is not very useful.  When you store an Object in `.Items`, the result of the `.ToString` function is what displays.  In this case it will just display `System.Data.Datarow`

The best solution is what LarsTech suggested and use the existing datatable as the datasource.  This is economical because there is nothing new created for the CBO:

```
ComboBox.DataSource = fooDataTable 
ComboBox.DisplayMember = "column name in DT"
```

Another way is to modify your loop:

```
combobox.Items.Add(row("col name").ToString)
```

This adds the data from the column name to the cbo.  If this was something like peoples names and you wanted to show First and Last name:

```
combobox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}, {1}", row("LastName").ToString,
                   row("FirstName").ToString))
```

This is similar except we are formatting the contents of both columns as we add it to the CBO.

Still another way is to create a class object for each row which returns what you want to display via the `ToString` override; and add them to the CBO, but that is overkill in this case, given the economy of the first alternative.